# Firebase Queries In a Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am struggling with the Firebase Queries, I have this Factory:

```
.factory("usuariosFac", ["$firebaseArray","$q","$firebaseObject",
    function($firebaseArray,$q,$firebaseObject) {
      return {

        getByEmail: function(email){
          var ref = firebase.database().ref("usuarios");
          var query=ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).on("child_added", function(data) {
            console.log(data.val());
            return data.val();
          });
        }
      }

    }
])
```

This function is in my Controller:

```
$scope.findUser = function() {
    $scope.usuario=usuariosFac.traeGrupoPorEmail($scope.formLogin.usuario);
};
```

When I run it, the console Log inside the Factory prints fine. But `$scope.usuario` is Undefined, why is this?

Comment: Where does the function `traeGrupoPorEmail` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But `$scope.usuario` is Undefined, why is this?

The callback function is being called *asychronously*. The `return` statement inside a *nested* function does not return values to the parent function.

Instead, create and return a promise:

```
app.factory("usuariosFac", ["$firebaseArray","$q","$firebaseObject",
    function($firebaseArray,$q,$firebaseObject) {
      return {

        getByEmail: function(email){
          //Create defer object
          var future = $q.defer();
          var ref = firebase.database().ref("usuarios");
          var query=ref.orderByChild("email")
            .equalTo(email)
            .once("child_added",
                function onSuccess(data) {
                   console.log(data.val());
                   //RESOLVE
                   future.resolve(data.val());
                },
                function onReject(error) {
                   //OR REJECT
                   future.reject(error);
                }
            );
          //RETURN promise
          return future.promise;
        }
      }

    }
])
```

In the controller, use the `.then` method of the returned promise:

```
$scope.findUser = function() {
    var promise = usuariosFac.traeGrupoPorEmail($scope.formLogin.usuario);
    promise.then(function onSuccess(data) {
        $scope.usuario = data;
    }).catch(function onReject(error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, is working perfectly. I think the "Once" function, did that.